# linux apache xml: setup cron-job / automation to retrieve xml

Tags: xml, linux, apache, automation, cron

I'm looking to setup a cronjob to automate the process of retrieving a local copy of a non-local xml file. (Every hour is good.)

XML file

```
https://AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD:x@myaccount.wufoo.com/api/v3/reports/123456/entries.xml
```

Local location and rename of file

```
/home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml
```

Comment: I think this should go on ServerFault?

Comment: Despite my answer below, I agree that ServerFault is a better place for this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use serverfault for linux questions next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a command that's something like

```
wget -O /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml https://AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD:x@myaccount.wufoo.com/api/v3/reports/123456/entries.xml
```

Your cron entry should look something like

```
0 * * * * wget -O /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml https://AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD:x@myaccount.wufoo.com/api/v3/reports/123456/entries.xml
```

This will run every hour on the hour.  If you're going to put it in the system-wide /etc/crontab, be you'll need to include the user to run as:

```
0 * * * * username wget -O /home/www/inc/xml/wufoo.xml https://AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD:x@myaccount.wufoo.com/api/v3/reports/123456/entries.xml
```

In either case, be sure to run as a user with restricted permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Create executable script (root owned) in file: /etc/cron.daily/my-script-name

In that script, use wget command. See "man wget" for details.
In general, you will need in that script:

```
wget -O /path/to/the/local/copy "https://someurl.com/path/to/the/remote/resource"
```

You may need to use "--no-check-certificate" for "https" protocol.